# Using NLTK and Lin thesarus for Synonyms replacement?

Tags: python, nltk, synonym

Succeded in using NLTK stop words and Lin thesaurus to find nearby meaning for certain words in the sentence

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords, lin_thesaurus as thes
sentence = "The door is made of glass"
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
print [thes.synonyms(i,fileid="simN.lsp") for i in sentence.lower().split() if i not in stop]
```

Question?

1.How to "Find and replace" a random synonym from the list?

2. Lin thesaurus gives scored synonyms, Is it possible to calculate 1% band across identified word and randomly select a word within that band and replace it.

For example suppose door is 1 and to check for a word within variance of 0.09 plus or minus and replace it.

Comment: Is it a non-trivial question? Is the question needs to be rephrased?